# What is the object involved in an Object Lock in SQL Server Profiler's Deadlock graph?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, deadlock, profiler, deadlock-graph

In searching documentation online, I have found that there can be row, page, or table locks.  However, I ran a SQL Server Profiler trace and noticed both a Page Lock and an Object lock.  I can easily discern the table involved in the Page lock from the "Object name".  However, the Object lock does not give any further details.  How can I know what the non-victim process locked?c

[image]

Comment: Post the full deadlock XML.